# Error: Serialization Scheme Not Supported

Tags: corda

When I run my Spring Boot webserver inside my GCP VM using this command:

```
java -jar corda-webserver.jar --server.port=10055 --config.rpc.host=localhost --config.rpc.port=10003 --config.rpc.username=cordazoneservice --config.rpc.password=SOME_PASSWORD
```

I get this error:

```
W 21:56:07 26 SerializationFactoryImpl.apply - Cannot find serialization scheme for: [([636F7264610000], RPCClient), UNKNOWN MAGIC] registeredSchemes are: [net.corda.client.rpc.internal.serialization.amqp.AMQPClientSerializationScheme@72fcf0f7]
E 21:56:07 26 RPCClientProxyHandler.artemisMessageHandler - Failed to deserialize RPC body
 net.corda.nodeapi.RPCApi$ServerToClient$FailedToDeserializeReply: Failed to deserialize RPC reply: Serialization scheme ([636F7264610000], RPCClient) not supported.
        at net.corda.nodeapi.RPCApi$ServerToClient$Companion.fromClientMessage(RPCApi.kt:240) ~[corda-node-api-4.1.jar!/:?]
        at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.artemisMessageHandler(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:309) ~[corda-rpc-4.1.jar!/:?]
        at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.access$artemisMessageHandler(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:75) ~[corda-rpc-4.1.jar!/:?]
        at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler$initSessions$1.invoke(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:519) ~[corda-rpc-4.1.jar!/:?]
        at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler$initSessions$1.invoke(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:75) ~[corda-rpc-4.1.jar!/:?]
        at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandlerKt$sam$org_apache_activemq_artemis_api_core_client_MessageHandler$0.onMessage(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt) ~[corda-rpc-4.1.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1002) ~[artemis-core-client-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$400(ClientConsumerImpl.java:50) ~[artemis-core-client-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1125) ~[artemis-core-client-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) ~[artemis-commons-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) ~[artemis-commons-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:66) ~[artemis-commons-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_222]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Serialization scheme ([636F7264610000], RPCClient) not supported.
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl$schemeFor$1.apply(SerializationScheme.kt:99) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar!/:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl$schemeFor$1.apply(SerializationScheme.kt:73) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar!/:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl.schemeFor(SerializationScheme.kt:95) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar!/:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl.access$schemeFor(SerializationScheme.kt:73) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar!/:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:105) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar!/:?]
        at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.withCurrentContext(SerializationAPI.kt:71) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar!/:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:105) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar!/:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:73) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar!/:?]
        at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.asCurrent(SerializationAPI.kt:85) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar!/:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl.deserialize(SerializationScheme.kt:105) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar!/:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.RPCApi$ServerToClient$Companion.fromClientMessage(RPCApi.kt:373) ~[corda-node-api-4.1.jar!/:?]
        ... 14 more
I 21:56:07 1 RPCClient.logElapsedTime - Failed Startup took 1204 msec
W 21:56:07 1 AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'nodeRPCConnection': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Serialization scheme ([636F7264610000], RPCClient) not supported.
I 21:56:07 1 StandardService.log - Stopping service [Tomcat]
```

Below is the Corda version that I use in my project:

```
corda_release_group = 'net.corda'
corda_release_version = '4.1'
tokens_release_group = 'com.r3.corda.lib.tokens'
tokens_release_version = '1.0-RC03'
corda_gradle_plugins_version = '4.0.42'
junit_version = '4.12'
quasar_version = '0.7.10'
spring_boot_version = '2.0.2.RELEASE'
spring_boot_gradle_plugin_version = '2.0.2.RELEASE'
slf4j_version = '1.7.25'
log4j_version = '2.11.2'
corda_platform_version = '4'
```

My Corda node on GCP VM that I built using the script from Corda TestNet:

```
[INFO ] 2019-08-14T03:21:28,879Z [main] internal.Node.logStartupInfo - Vendor: Corda Open Source {}
[INFO ] 2019-08-14T03:21:28,879Z [main] internal.Node.logStartupInfo - Release: 3.3-corda {}
[INFO ] 2019-08-14T03:21:28,881Z [main] internal.Node.logStartupInfo - Platform Version: 3 {}
```

Btw, I don't get errors when I run that command on my local Ubuntu VM; I start the node, then the webserver and I can access it inside my browser. This error only happens when I try the same inside my GCP VM using the node that is supplied by Corda TestNet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded my node from OS 3.3 to OS 4.1 and that solved the issue.
Make sure you update `node.conf` file inside your node folder to follow the new formatting (e.g. no double quotes around keys).